# Add custom taxonomy term in woocommerce REST API

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I have created custom taxonomy "Brands" and attached to woocommerce products. Unfortunately, It is not available in woocommerce REST API response.
How to attach custom taxonomy term to woocommerce rest API. Currently there is no documentation about attachment of custom taxonomy. Is there any hook or filter ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved by using this code.You will be able to GET and Update custom taxonomy by using this method. Basically. You can add this code in `functions.php` file or in `plugin`.

**Step:1**
Replace `brands` with your `taxonomy_name`.

**Step:2**
If your taxonomy have custom fields, replace `custom_field_name` with yours.

**Taxonomy Code:**

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_brands_hierarchical_taxonomy', 0 );

//create a custom taxonomy name it topics for your posts
 
function create_brands_hierarchical_taxonomy() {
 
// Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical like categories
//first do the translations part for GUI
 
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Brands', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Brand', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Brands' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'All Brands' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Brand' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Brand:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Brand' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Update Brand' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Brand' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'New Brand Name' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Brands' ),
  );    
  
    $capabilities = array(
        'manage_terms'               => 'manage_woocommerce',
        'edit_terms'                 => 'manage_woocommerce',
        'delete_terms'               => 'manage_woocommerce',
        'assign_terms'               => 'manage_woocommerce',
    ); 
 
// Now register the taxonomy
     $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'show_in_rest'               => true,       
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'capabilities'               => $capabilities,
        
    
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'brands', array( 'product' ), $args );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'brands', 'product' );

 
}
```

**Register Taxonomy API for WC**

```
//Register taxonomy API for WC
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_rest_field_for_custom_taxonomy_brands' );
function register_rest_field_for_custom_taxonomy_brands() {
    

    register_rest_field('product', "brands", array(
        'get_callback'    => 'product_get_callback',
        'update_callback'    => 'product_update_callback',
        'schema' => null,
    ));    

}
        //Get Taxonomy record in wc REST API
         function product_get_callback($post, $attr, $request, $object_type)
        {
            $terms = array();

            // Get terms
            foreach (wp_get_post_terms( $post[ 'id' ],'brands') as $term) {
                $terms[] = array(
                    'id'        => $term->term_id,
                    'name'      => $term->name,
                    'slug'      => $term->slug,
                    'custom_field_name'  => get_term_meta($term->term_id, 'custom_field_name', true)
                );
            }

            return $terms;
        }
        
         //Update Taxonomy record in wc REST API
         function product_update_callback($values, $post, $attr, $request, $object_type)
        {   
            // Post ID
            $postId = $post->get_id();
            
            //Example: $values = [2,4,3];                
            
            // Set terms
           wp_set_object_terms( $postId, $values , 'brands');
            
            
        }
```

Comment: So does this then allow you to add a new product to WooCommerce via the REST API and also include adding data to the custom taxonomies?

Answer (score 1):

Solution above is working but you have to change the

```
$postId = $post->get_id();
```

with

```
$postId = $post->ID;
```

Comment: Yeah, you can adjust to according your need. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Took me ages to find out why update_callback did not work : $values contains the taxonomy-structure and is therefore too complex to pass as integer to wp_set_object_terms. You have to strip it to the numeric ID's only otherwise [null] is assigned

```
//Update Taxonomy record in wc REST API
     function product_update_callback_Leerjaar($values, $post, $attr, $request, $object_type)
    {   
        // Post ID            
        $postId = $post->id;
        
        //Example: $values = [2,4,3];    
 
         error_log("debug on values");
         error_log(json_encode($values));
                         
         $numarray = [];             
         foreach($values as $value){
             $numarray[] = (int)$value['id'];
         }
          
       wp_set_object_terms( $postId, $numarray , 'brands');
        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has tested all the above and can't get it to work, I found a simplest and working solution, based on Taha Farooqui's answer and the wordpress register_rest_field  [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_field/)  :

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_rest_field_for_custom_taxonomy_brands');
function register_rest_field_for_custom_taxonomy_brands() {
    register_rest_field('product', "field_rest_name",
        array("get_callback" => function ($post) {
            $taxonomy = wp_get_post_terms( $post['id'], 'your_taxonomy_name');
                return $taxonomy;
            }
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After months of testing trying to prove why the product_update_callback() function returned a null value, he got a version that loads the taxonomy values ​​from the woocommerce Rest Api v3 only with the name and slug..

```
<?php
//Prevent a malicious user from executing php code from the browser bar
defined('ABSPATH') or die( "Bye bye" );


add_action( 'init', 'create_brands_hierarchical_taxonomy', 0 );

//create a custom taxonomy name it topics for your posts
 
function create_brands_hierarchical_taxonomy() {
 
// Add new taxonomy, make it hierarchical like categories
 
  $labels = array(
    'name' => _x( 'Marcas', 'taxonomy general name' ),
    'singular_name' => _x( 'Marca', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
    'search_items' =>  __( 'Buscar Marcas' ),
    'all_items' => __( 'Todas las Marcas' ),
    'parent_item' => __( 'Marca Relacionada' ),
    'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Marca Relacionada:' ),
    'edit_item' => __( 'Editar Marca' ), 
    'update_item' => __( 'Subir Marca' ),
    'add_new_item' => __( 'Añadir Nueva Marca' ),
    'new_item_name' => __( 'Nuevo Nombre de Marca' ),
    'menu_name' => __( 'Marcas' ),
  );    
  
    $capabilities = array(
        'manage_terms'               => 'manage_woocommerce',
        'edit_terms'                 => 'manage_woocommerce',
        'delete_terms'               => 'manage_woocommerce',
        'assign_terms'               => 'manage_woocommerce',
    ); 
 
// Now register the taxonomy
     $args = array(
        'labels'                     => $labels,
        'show_in_rest'               => true,       
        'hierarchical'               => true,
        'public'                     => true,
        'show_ui'                    => true,
        'show_admin_column'          => false,
        'show_in_nav_menus'          => true,
        'show_tagcloud'              => true,
        'capabilities'               => $capabilities,
        
    
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'pwb-brand', array( 'product' ), $args );
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'pwb-brand', 'product' );

 
}
```

```
//Register taxonomy API for WC
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_rest_field_for_custom_taxonomy_brands' );
function register_rest_field_for_custom_taxonomy_brands() {
    

    register_rest_field('product', "pwb-brand", array(
        'get_callback'    => 'product_get_callback_brand',
        'update_callback'    => 'product_update_callback_brand',
        'schema' => null,
    ));    

}
```

```
        //Get Taxonomy record in wc REST API
function product_get_callback_brand($post, $attr, $request, $object_type){
            
    $terms = array();

            // Get terms
            foreach (wp_get_post_terms( $post[ 'id' ],'pwb-brand') as $term) {
                $terms[] = array(
                    'id'        => $term->term_id,
                    'name'      => $term->name,
                    'slug'      => $term->slug,
                );
            }

            return $terms;
}
```

```
//Update Taxonomy record in wc REST API
function product_update_callback_brand($values, $post, $attr, $request, $object_type){   
    // Post ID            
    $postId = $post->id;

    $terms = $values;
    
    $termName = $terms[0]['name'];
    $termSlug = $terms[0]['slug'];

    wp_insert_term( $termName, 'pwb-brand', array( 'slug' => $termSlug ) );

     error_log("debug on values");
     error_log(json_encode($values));

     $newTermId = get_term_by('slug',$termSlug,'pwb-brand')->term_id;

     array_push($values, array('id' => (int)$newTermId));
                     
     $numarray = [];             
     foreach($values as $value){         
         if(is_numeric($value['id'])){             
             $numarray[] = (int)$value['id'];          
         }       
    }
      
   wp_set_object_terms( $postId, $numarray , 'pwb-brand');
}
```

After so much testing he understood that the values ​​that pass through the product_get_callback_brand function are mandatory to register a taxonomy so if you add a custom field like in the first example then they must be loaded so that the taxonomy can be retrieved.

It is worth noting that it is not a valid field for image fields or galleries that will not have the permissions to be loaded by the Rest Api v3 of woocommerce